# Would like to create a variable in ASP to change a value

Tags: sql, asp-classic

Just updated my question. But I have an array

```
Dim divName(3) 'Fixed size array
divName(0) = "DIV1"
divName(1) = "DIV2"
divName(2) = "DIV3"
```

I would like to apply one particular value ("DIV1") from my array within my SQL query

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM DivisionNew814 WHERE JMS_UpdateDateTime >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()) AND  Division ='" & divName (divrec(0)) &"' order by JMS_UpdateDateTime desc"
```

It's not working.

"Divrec" is a variable that outputs to "Division 1" I would like to change that value to "DIV1" using my array within the SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output a array value you need to use the index:

```
Dim divName(3) 'Fixed size array
divName(0) = "DIV1"
divName(1) = "DIV2"
divName(2) = "DIV3"


... AND  Division ='" & divName(0) &"' order by ...
```

If you need the conversion from "Division 1" to "DIV1" and if its always like "Division X" to "DIVX" you could to a replace:

```
... AND  Division ='" & Replace(divrec(0), "Division ", "DIV") &"' order by ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%
if divrec = "Division 1" then
  divrec = "Div1"
end if
%>
```

Comment: I was able to use this as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is a key-value collection, meaning something that will "translate" the text "Division 1" to "DIV1". For this, we have the Scripting.Dictionary object:

```
Dim divNames
Set divNames = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
divNames.Add "Division 1", "DIV1"
divNames.Add "Division 2", "DIV2"
divNames.Add "Division 3", "DIV3"
```

And then:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM DivisionNew814 WHERE JMS_UpdateDateTime >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()) AND  Division ='" & divNames(divrec(0)) &"' order by JMS_UpdateDateTime desc"
```

If `divrec` is only a string then change to:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM DivisionNew814 WHERE JMS_UpdateDateTime >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()) AND  Division ='" & divNames(divrec) &"' order by JMS_UpdateDateTime desc"
```